# Complex function for getting combinations of one column with other

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table in pandas df

```
id_x  id_y
a      b
b      c
a      c
d      a
x      a
m      b
c      z
a      k
b      q
d      w
a      w
q      v
```

How to read this table is :

the combinations for a is, a-b,a-c,a-k,a-w, similarly for b(b-c,b-q) and so on..
I want to write a function which takes id_x from the df `def test_func(id)`

and check whether the occurrences of that id is greater than 3 or not, which may be done by `df['id_x'].value_counts` .

for eg.

```
def test_func(id):
    if id_count >= 3:
       print 'yes'
       ddf = df[df['id_x'] == id]
       ddf.to_csv(id+".csv")
    else:
       print 'no'
       while id_count <3:
           # do something.(I've explained below what I have to do when count<3)
```

Say for b the occurrence is only 2(i.e b-c, and b-q) which is less than 3.

so in such case, look if 'c'(from id_y) has any combinations.

c has 1 combination(c-z) and similarly q has 1 combination(q-v)

thus b should be linked with z and v.

```
id_x   id_y
b       c
b       q
b       z
b       v
```

and store it in ddf2 like we stored for >10.

Also for particular id,if I could have csv saved with the name of id. 
I hope I explained my question correctly, I am very new to python and I don't know to write functions, this was my logic.

Can anyone help me with the implementation part.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You tagged both Python2.7 and Python3, you need a compatible code for both versions?

Comment: @Adirio Any one of the versions would be fine,not necessarily both.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:** solution redesign according to comments

```
import pandas as pd

def direct_related(df, values, column_names=('x', 'y')):
    rels = set()
    for value in values:
        for i, v in df[df[column_names[0]]==value][column_names[1]].iteritems():
            rels.add(v)
    return rels


def indirect_related(df, values, recursion=1, column_names=('x', 'y')):
    rels = direct_related(df, values, column_names)
    for i in range(recursion):
        rels = rels.union(direct_related(df, rels, column_names))
    return rels

def related(df, value, recursion=1, column_names=('x', 'y')):
    rels = indirect_related(df, [value], recursion, column_names)
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {
            column_names[0]: value,
            column_names[1]: list(rels)
        }
    )

def min_related(df, value, min_appearances=3, max_recursion=10, column_names=('x', 'y')):
    for i in range(max_recursion + 1):
        if len(indirect_related(df, [value], i, column_names)) >= min_appearances:
            return related(df, value, i, column_names)
    return None

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'x', 'm', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'q'],
        'y': ['b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'z', 'k', 'q', 'w', 'w', 'v']
    }
)

print(min_related(df, 'b', 3))
```

Comment: can you make it recursive? i mean, for n indirect relations.

Comment: Search of all the indirect relations associated with that letter.
fr eg. i ran your code `text_func(b)` for finding relations for b. and i got only z(which is indirect relation with c (b-c, c-z)  but q i also in relation with b(b-q and q-v) .therefore 'b' should have relationship with v also

Comment: yes my bad, i rechecked it again, by the way, can i concatenate the indirect relations with my direct relation instead?  i mean running your code give me only indirect relations in a df, i want the direct relations too

Comment: @SRingne check if this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

First [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) `DataFrame` by `length` (for testing `< 3`)

```
a = df.groupby('id_x').filter(lambda x: len(x) < 3)
print (a)
   id_x id_y
1     b    c
3     d    a
4     x    a
5     m    b
6     c    z
8     b    q
9     d    w
11    q    v
```

Then filter where `b` and rename columns:

```
a1 = a.query("id_x == 'b'").rename(columns={'id_y':'id'})
print (a1)
  id_x id
1    b  c
8    b  q
```

Also filter where are NOT b:

```
a2 = a.query("id_y != 'b'").rename(columns={'id_x':'id'})
print (a2)
   id id_y
1   b    c
3   d    a
4   x    a
6   c    z
8   b    q
9   d    w
11  q    v
```

Then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) by column `id`:

```
b = pd.merge(a1,a2, on='id').drop('id', axis=1)
print (b)
  id_x id_y
0    b    z
1    b    v
```

Last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) filtered by b to new dataframe `b`:

```
c = pd.concat([a.query("id_x == 'b'"), b])
print (c)
  id_x id_y
1    b    c
8    b    q
0    b    z
1    b    v
```